mlr3 training error during tunning with Deepsurv and loghaz
I'm studying ML performance in case of severe censoring.
With 50% censoring, Deepsurv with tuning fails in two out of five folds. However, with 90% censoring, all five folds fail with the error.

Error in check_prediction_data.PredictionDataSurv(pdata, train_task = task) : 
  Assertion on 'pdata$crank' failed: Contains missing values (element 1).


Interestingly, Deepsurv with tuning works fine with three folds and 90% censoring.
This issue was posted in SO here and here without reproducible data and resolved at mlr3's GitHub: Error on missing values without missing values The issue was found and described as very unbalanced dataset cause some of the cross-validation resamples not to include all of the labels. Unfortunately, I tried the first solution offered by @mllg during task instantiation but without luck.
A less problematic issue occurs with Survival Logistic-Hazard Learner in a few runs with the error.
> #Without pipelines
> Error in assert_surv_matrix(x) :    Survival probabilities must be
> (non-strictly) decreasing and between [0, 1]

> #With pipelines
> Error in assert_surv_matrix(x) :    Survival probabilities must be
> (non-strictly) decreasing and between [0, 1] This happened PipeOp
> ml_ann_loghaz.tuned's $train()

My first thought is that tuning does not respect the task role "stratum" during instantiation.
Of course, there is an easy solution to reduce the number of folds, as I did earlier (5 to 3) but I hope for a more realistic solution.
Here is a sample code:
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3proba)
library(mlr3extralearners)
library(mlr3tuning) #AutoTuner
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(reticulate)
# control Pyhon warnings through reticulate:
warnings <- import("warnings")
# ignore / suppress:
warnings$simplefilter("ignore")

search_space_ann = ps(
  dropout = p_dbl(lower = 0, upper = 1),
  weight_decay = p_dbl(lower = 0, upper = 0.5),
  learning_rate = p_dbl(lower = 0, upper = 1),
  num_layers = p_int(lower = 1, upper = 4),
  num_nodes_per_layer = p_int(lower = 1, upper = 32),
  .extra_trafo = function(x, param_set) {
    x$num_nodes = rep(x$num_nodes_per_layer, x$num_layers)
    x$num_layers = NULL
    x$num_nodes_per_layer = NULL
    x
  }
)

#as_learner(po("scale") %>>% 
at_lrn_deepsurv = auto_tuner(
  learner = lrn("surv.deepsurv", 
                id = "ml_ann_deepsurv", frac = 0.3,
                optimizer = "adam", early_stopping = TRUE, epochs = 100),
  search_space = search_space_ann,
  resampling = rsmp_tune_cv,
  measure = msr("surv.cindex"),
  terminator = trm_tune,
  tuner = tnr("random_search")
) 
   
at_lrn_loghaz = auto_tuner(
  learner = lrn("surv.loghaz", 
                id = "ml_ann_loghaz", frac = 0.3,
                optimizer = "adam", early_stopping = TRUE, epochs = 100),
  search_space = search_space_ann,
  resampling = rsmp_tune_cv,
  measure = msr("surv.cindex"),
  terminator = trm_tune,
  tuner = tnr("random_search")
) 

#df <- read_csv("simulation_data/PH_90_500_linear/sim_seed_1134.csv")
tsk_sim = as_task_surv(df, time = "time", event = "event", type = "right", id = "sim1")
tsk_sim$set_col_roles("event", c("target", "stratum"))

set.seed(1)
rsmp_tune_cv = rsmp("holdout")
trm_tune = trm("evals", n_evals = 100)

set.seed(1)
rsmp_outer_5cv = rsmp("cv", folds = 5)
rsmp_outer_5cv$instantiate(tsk_sim)

rsmp_outer_3cv = rsmp("cv", folds = 3)
rsmp_outer_3cv$instantiate(tsk_sim)

#Error
set.seed(1)
at_lrn_deepsurv$train(tsk_sim, row_ids = rsmp_outer_5cv$train_set(1))
INFO  [16:24:38.892] [bbotk] Starting to optimize 5 parameter(s) with '<OptimizerBatchRandomSearch>' and '<TerminatorEvals> [n_evals=100, k=0]'
INFO  [16:24:38.977] [bbotk] Evaluating 1 configuration(s)
INFO  [16:24:38.994] [mlr3] Running benchmark with 1 resampling iterations
INFO  [16:24:39.008] [mlr3] Applying learner 'ml_ann_deepsurv' on task 'sim1' (iter 1/1)
...
INFO  [16:24:40.759] [mlr3] Finished benchmark
INFO  [16:24:40.812] [bbotk] Result of batch 7:
INFO  [16:24:40.818] [bbotk]    dropout weight_decay learning_rate num_layers num_nodes_per_layer surv.cindex warnings
INFO  [16:24:40.818] [bbotk]  0.6097489    0.1321245     0.4230986          2                  31   0.6007143        0
INFO  [16:24:40.818] [bbotk]  errors runtime_learners                                uhash
INFO  [16:24:40.818] [bbotk]       0            0.113 544d865f-4801-488d-83e5-2e30ce55b80c
INFO  [16:24:40.850] [bbotk] Evaluating 1 configuration(s)
INFO  [16:24:40.869] [mlr3] Running benchmark with 1 resampling iterations
INFO  [16:24:40.882] [mlr3] Applying learner 'ml_ann_deepsurv' on task 'sim1' (iter 1/1)

Error in check_prediction_data.PredictionDataSurv(pdata, train_task = task) : 
  Assertion on 'pdata$crank' failed: Contains missing values (element 1).

#No Error
set.seed(1)
lrn("surv.deepsurv")$train(tsk_sim, row_ids = rsmp_outer_5cv$train_set(1))
#No Error
set.seed(1)
at_lrn_deepsurv$train(tsk_sim, row_ids = rsmp_outer_3cv$train_set(1))

#Error after 2 to 3 trials
set.seed(1)
at_lrn_loghaz$train(tsk_sim, row_ids = rsmp_outer_5cv$train_set(1))
Error in assert_surv_matrix(x) : 
  Survival probabilities must be (non-strictly) decreasing and between [0, 1]

Here is the data
df <- structure(list(age = c(64, 47, 52, 70, 62, 59, 38, 63, 61, 51, 
57, 63, 61, 69, 66, 69, 52, 66, 40, 66, 56, 66, 52, 60, 54, 68, 
52, 60, 57, 54, 43, 67, 54, 60, 62, 68, 66, 61, 61, 58, 61, 54, 
68, 66, 59, 57, 58, 67, 50, 57, 67, 60, 59, 44, 48, 47, 52, 66, 
64, 65, 62, 68, 45, 65, 53, 61, 55, 60, 64, 66, 59, 59, 48, 61, 
55, 54, 62, 53, 59, 57, 57, 52, 70, 64, 57, 62, 57, 55, 63, 63, 
51, 54, 63, 45, 63, 57, 66, 63, 65, 54, 59, 64, 53, 57, 61, 64, 
61, 44, 53, 64, 69, 69, 64, 55, 69, 56, 49, 40, 58, 66, 66, 62, 
64, 61, 66, 58, 63, 60, 50, 69, 57, 39, 49, 59, 54, 63, 57, 35, 
61, 55, 41, 52, 67, 58, 60, 50, 60, 62, 69, 70, 62, 53, 51, 57, 
57, 62, 64, 65, 57, 59, 31, 60, 69, 64, 44, 53, 63, 67, 62, 55, 
70, 63, 51, 37, 50, 60, 62, 52, 62, 57, 58, 51, 46, 58, 48, 57, 
49, 57, 59, 60, 54, 54, 49, 49, 56, 67, 50, 52, 59, 58, 59, 59, 
67, 53, 68, 59, 65, 55, 49, 51, 51, 64, 47, 65, 48, 58, 38, 68, 
63, 59, 65, 45, 69, 61, 51, 49, 43, 63, 39, 51, 62, 59, 58, 67, 
57, 62, 64, 59, 60, 67, 54, 38, 52, 48, 54, 55, 57, 50, 65, 65, 
61, 68, 56, 57, 67, 64, 64, 56, 59, 63, 55, 65, 63, 60, 57, 68, 
59, 61, 40, 50, 66, 56, 55, 55, 56, 62, 49, 56, 54, 62, 57, 62, 
52, 59, 70, 55, 64, 65, 57, 66, 61, 64, 55, 66, 56, 67, 68, 60, 
60, 50, 68, 54, 65, 61, 51, 57, 69, 63, 56, 54, 58, 70, 32, 64, 
56, 56, 67, 58, 66, 65, 65, 67, 64, 55, 55, 63, 62, 67, 42, 58, 
64, 63, 62, 58, 58, 59, 48, 62, 55, 55, 55, 49, 52, 56, 54, 64, 
68, 46, 65, 69, 58, 59, 69, 62, 58, 63, 65, 61, 50, 49, 52, 59, 
59, 53, 48, 45, 63, 58, 62, 66, 57, 45, 52, 49, 64, 69, 68, 60, 
56, 65, 42, 49, 66, 59, 40, 68, 62, 69, 53, 49, 53, 58, 51, 66, 
68, 62, 64, 56, 54, 51, 65, 58, 49, 60, 63, 69, 63, 68, 60, 55, 
67, 62, 57, 55, 67, 69, 67, 50, 55, 63, 57, 60, 60, 56, 47, 65, 
60, 63, 49, 61, 49, 69, 62, 51, 54, 67, 70, 55, 69, 62, 59, 60, 
69, 69, 51, 60, 59, 42, 65, 63, 66, 59, 40, 62, 61, 70, 59, 62, 
67, 64, 53, 68, 65, 60, 55, 46, 52, 65, 45, 60, 67, 47, 58, 53, 
62, 52, 53, 56, 50, 59, 57, 63, 59, 68, 60, 56, 68, 60, 56, 49, 
58, 58, 58, 67, 60, 49, 65, 67, 64, 58), gender = c(0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), event = c(0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), time = c(2, 15, 12, 
1, 2, 9, 21, 1, 6, 4, 1, 2, 7, 4, 10, 2, 1, 4, 11, 1, 7, 4, 7, 
11, 2, 1, 4, 9, 5, 4, 17, 6, 13, 6, 4, 5, 1, 7, 8, 6, 1, 10, 
1, 7, 8, 4, 14, 4, 6, 14, 2, 7, 1, 13, 13, 5, 3, 1, 5, 4, 3, 
4, 25, 1, 7, 7, 6, 2, 2, 2, 10, 2, 9, 6, 4, 7, 6, 4, 11, 11, 
1, 9, 6, 1, 3, 15, 13, 3, 2, 5, 17, 2, 3, 7, 3, 1, 3, 2, 7, 3, 
8, 5, 4, 1, 7, 3, 2, 3, 17, 5, 6, 2, 9, 1, 5, 7, 3, 1, 6, 6, 
1, 5, 6, 3, 6, 2, 5, 2, 17, 1, 7, 18, 9, 5, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
10, 1, 4, 12, 5, 5, 5, 7, 10, 1, 4, 2, 7, 13, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 7, 1, 1, 6, 3, 2, 5, 24, 8, 5, 8, 18, 2, 
4, 15, 10, 3, 3, 2, 11, 4, 7, 7, 2, 13, 8, 29, 9, 4, 1, 27, 17, 
1, 8, 5, 2, 1, 10, 3, 1, 12, 8, 3, 9, 3, 8, 2, 3, 15, 5, 2, 3, 
4, 4, 2, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 16, 1, 19, 4, 1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 1, 3, 4, 
2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 4, 10, 12, 2, 16, 9, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 4, 2, 4, 5, 
5, 7, 2, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 8, 10, 4, 6, 4, 7, 7, 13, 4, 11, 1, 7, 
5, 9, 2, 8, 9, 13, 14, 1, 8, 7, 3, 3, 10, 1, 3, 4, 8, 5, 5, 3, 
8, 8, 2, 18, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 7, 4, 1, 11, 29, 2, 3, 12, 3, 
6, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 19, 10, 2, 2, 8, 5, 5, 1, 4, 7, 4, 4, 8, 
5, 4, 7, 7, 1, 8, 5, 2, 8, 2, 2, 11, 1, 6, 2, 1, 9, 2, 6, 2, 
12, 7, 6, 3, 14, 3, 6, 1, 30, 1, 9, 4, 2, 11, 6, 2, 8, 10, 2, 
7, 4, 10, 7, 12, 13, 1, 7, 9, 6, 6, 1, 2, 1, 14, 6, 7, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 6, 2, 1, 9, 15, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 7, 4, 6, 2, 2, 9, 2, 
1, 5, 8, 12, 9, 4, 1, 12, 10, 6, 5, 7, 1, 16, 1, 7, 4, 1, 5, 
5, 6, 1, 1, 6, 17, 4, 1, 3, 4, 19, 4, 6, 13, 8, 3, 1, 20, 18, 
10, 7, 1, 7, 10, 2, 7, 15, 4, 3, 1, 13, 16, 7, 7, 4, 2, 3, 14, 
6, 3, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 2, 9, 8, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 11, 8, 16, 7, 
9, 3, 2, 8, 3, 4, 1, 18)), row.names = c(NA, -500L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


When you say you tried the solution without luck, what do you mean? You shouldn't get the error anymore.

@LarsKotthoff thanks for your reply. As you can see in the code, I'm getting the error even though I added stratum as a role when defined the task tsk_sim$set_col_roles("event", c("target", "stratum")).

Both these errors/problems result from how the survival probabilities are calculated internally in the pycox package. In this code line, the survival matrix is returned and converted from Python. I see a specific survivalmodels::fill_na function that is trying to fill in NAs somehow, so the author was aware of the problem and tried to mitigate it as much as it was possible.
In your case a possible explanation might be that for a whole row/observation you get only NA's for surv probabilities, which is not between 0 and 1 and that triggers the error on the prediction data check step.
The crank predictions are directly calculated as the expected mortality with the survivalmodels::surv_to_risk function. This means that if somehow one of the probabilities is NA, this will cause the crank for that observation to be NA (ie missing), which will trigger the following error you saw:
Error in check_prediction_data.PredictionDataSurv(pdata, train_task = task) : 
  Assertion on 'pdata$crank' failed: Contains missing values (element 1).


I would advice to open an issue on pycox - in general every survival model that calculates survival probabilities on its own, should not return NAs, for any time point. Might be worth using a fallback learner (eg lrn("surv.kaplan")), which would save you from such errors when they happen in some folds during tuning.
